# Flex: Linebreak problem with spark.components.TextArea inside a MXDataGridItemRenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, textarea, line-breaks

I have a `DataGrid` that has a `MXDataGridItemRenderer` applied as an `itemEditor` to one of the columns. The editor includes a `spark.components.TextArea` control.

By default, any text item editor of a datagrid closes itself when [enter] key is pressed..
Keeping this in mind; What I want to do is:

1. Prevent editor from closing on [SHIFT+ENTER] key but accept the linebreak (I can do this, see code below)
2. Close the editor on [ENTER] key but do not accept the linebreak (could not achieve this)

Here is the current code in the `MXDataGridItemRenderer`:

```
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                      focusEnabled="true" 
                      >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        protected function onTxtDataKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (event.keyCode == 13)
            {
                if (event.shiftKey)
                {
                    //Prevent editor from closing on [SHIFT+ENTER] key but accept the linebreak
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation(); // » works
                }
                else
                {
                    //Close the editor on [ENTER] key but do not accept the linebreak
                    event.preventDefault(); // » does not work
                }
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:TextArea id="txtData" paddingTop="3" lineBreak="explicit"
            text="{dataGridListData.label}" 
            verticalScrollPolicy="auto" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" 
            keyDown="onTxtDataKeyDown(event)" 
            />
```

I also tried the `textInput` event but that did not do the trick.
So: How can I prevent the **linebreak** when the editor is closed on **[enter] key**?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:** If I change the spark.components.TextArea to mx.controls.TextArea, second part with `event.preventDefault()` will work as expected but then the first part where SHIFT+ENTER accepts the linebreak will not work.

Answer (score 1):

According to the API reference `keyDown` is cancellable only in AIR and not in Flash Player. Which one are you developing for? I was not able to cancel either `keyDown` or `textinput` in AIR. Could be a bug. Why don't you log a defect with Adobe and see what they say?

**Update**: I have confirmed that this is indeed a bug in `spark.components.TextArea`. The thread http://forums.adobe.com/thread/703195 talks about similar issue.A bug has been logged against Flex as well - http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-25542.

Workaround is to use `mx.controls.TextArea`.

Comment: As I said in the post; I've tried that before. That doesn't work with spark.components.TextArea. When you hit the enter key, textinput does not trace anything. Only traces if it is a regualr character key such as a,b,c..space,etc..

Comment: Cannot do that either. What if the text is selected in the textarea? Hitting enter will erase it all and only stripping the line break will not solve the problem.

Comment: I'm developing for AIR. Yes, seems like a bug.

Comment: In case you are still interested, I have confirmed that your problem is a defect and the flex team is aware of it. Updated answer with links to relevant discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good English. Please see code.

```
<!--snip-->
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        protected function textArea_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
            textArea.addEventListener(TextOperationEvent.CHANGING,onChangingHandler);
        }

        //This event is faster than KEY_DOWN.
        private function onChangingHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void {
            if(event.operation is SplitParagraphOperation){
                //SplitParagraphOperation only cancel.
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
  <s:TextArea id="textArea"
                    width="100"
                    creationComplete="textArea_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                    height="60"
                    />
  <!--snip-->
```